# Independence between RV and union of RVs

Tags: probability, independence

If random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $X$ and $Z$ are independent, are $X$ and $Y \cup Z$ independent?

Comment: What's the *union* of two random variables supposed to be?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I should clarify. $Y$ and $Z$ RVs denoting the occurence of events and $Y \cup Z$ is the RV associated with the union of the events occurence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

suppose you are tossing two coins, a penny and a dime.  $X$ is the event that the penny comes up $H$, $Y$ is the event that the dime comes up $H$, and $Z$ is the event that the coins match.  Then the events that comprise $Y\cup Z$ are $$HH,TH,TT\implies P(Y\cup Z)=\frac 34$$ 
Where $TH$, for example, denotes the event "the penny comes up $T$ and the dime comes up $H$".

But $$P\left(X\cap (Y\cup Z)\right)=\frac 14\neq P(X)\times P(Y\cup Z)$$

Comment: I think you meant X instead of B, and HT instead of TT.

Comment: @ndn  Thanks, I've already correct the $X,B$ typo.  But I think I am right about the other...$HT$ would mean that the dime came up $T$ and that the coins did not match, so that event is outside $Y\cup Z$.  $TT$ on the other hand means the coins did match.

Comment: Thank you. That clears my doubt.

Comment: I understand it is a different question, but if $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ were mutually independent, would the assertion be true?

Comment: @NivedRajaraman...Yes.  Note that the assumption implies that $X,Y',Z'$ are mutually independent and that the question regarding $Y\cup Z$ can be replaced with the question regarding $Y'\cap Z'$

Comment: @lulu Ah, yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No. The event $A_ i,_j$ that $i,j$ have the same birthdays is pairwise independent, so $A_1,_2$ and $A_2,_3$ are independent, as well as $A_1,_2$ and $A_1,_3$, but $A_1,_2, A_2,_3$ and $A_3,_1$ are clearly not independent. As person 1 having the same birthday as person 2 and person 3 having the same birthday as person 1 implies 2 and 3 have the same birthdays.